# RegEnumValue and REG_MULTI_SZ type

Tags: c, winapi, registry

MSDN says about string data got by RegEnumValue that

> If the data has the REG_SZ, REG_MULTI_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ type, the
>   string may not have been stored with the proper null-terminating
>   characters. Therefore, even if the function returns ERROR_SUCCESS, the
>   application should ensure that the string is properly terminated
>   before using it; otherwise, it may overwrite a buffer. (Note that
>   REG_MULTI_SZ strings should have two null-terminating characters.)

Suppose a value is REG_MULTI_SZ, does this mean that each of the strings in the sequence can or cannot be null-terminated, or just that only last double null terminator may be absent, but all inner null terminators are present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose a value is REG_MULTI_SZ, does this mean that each of the strings in the sequence can or cannot be null-terminated

The strings in the sequence *must* be null terminated or else it would be impossible to determine where one of the string ends and the next string begins. From [Registry Value Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describing `REG_MULTI_SZ`:

```
A sequence of null-terminated strings, terminated by an empty string (\0).
The following is an example:

    String1\0String2\0String3\0LastString\0\0

The first \0 terminates the first string, the second to the last \0 terminates
the last string, and the final \0 terminates the sequence.
Note that the final terminator must be factored into the length of the string.
```

The documentation is vague but my interpretation is that the last null terminators may be missing:

```
String1\0String2\0String3\0LastString
```

and code reading the value must ensure they are present for subsequent string extraction.

If the buffer being used to contain the value is large enough, including space for the terminating null characters, as long as the code ensures the trailing nulls are present there is nothing to be concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take care just for the last terminator. Simply check if it's there or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very common bug in programs that handle C strings, they'll easily use strlen() or wcslen() to measure the string length and pass that as the *cbData* argument of RegSetValueEx().  Forgetting about the zero terminator, those off-by-one bugs are rampant.  Windows doesn't care, it just write bytes and doesn't try to interpret the string.

So what goes wrong is when you read the registry value, you'll get the bytes without the zero terminator.  If you then interpret it as a C string again, you'll have only 0.4% odds that you'll see the actual string, zero odds when you use a debug allocator.  You simply avoid it by writing the zero-terminator yourself.  If it is already there then it doesn't matter, modulo a possible buffer overrun, if not then you avoided your program using bad data.